# Creating an Array of Objects in Range Loop Golang

Tags: arrays, go, goland

I am a newbie in Golang and trying out things. I have two requirements,

1. Print the Number of Occurrences of the Values in an Array - This is done.
2. Creating a Key-Value of the Key and the Value in an Array - Still working on it.

Let me share, what I have I done till now. I have array of Strings

`var StringsArray :=["Person1","Person2","Person3","Person4","Person1","Person2"]`

I am looping over this,

```
for _, name := range StringsArray {
   Count := make(map[string]int)
   Words []string
   type MyStruct struct {
      Name string `json:"name" bson:"name" `
      Count int  `json:"count" bson:"count" `
   }
   _, exist := Count[name]
   if exist {
      Count[name] += 1
   } else {
      Count[name] = 1
   }
   if name != "" {
      fmt.Println("m",name, Count)
      WordsArray := []MyStruct {
         {
           name: name,
           count: Count[name],
         }
      }
      Words = append(Words,WordsArray)
   }
}
```

I am expecting a Output as Array of Objects like

```
[{name:"Person1", value:2},{name:"Person2", value:2},{name:"Person3", value:1},{name:"Person4", value:1}]
```

But I am not getting the intended output. below is my Output

```
[
 {Person2 2}
]
```

The other Values are overridden.

Any help on this is highly Appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "But I am not getting the intended output" what output *are* you getting?

Comment: I see a number of problems with your code which suggest it wouldn't even compile. You define `Words` twice, one right after the other; you're trying to append a `[]MyStruct` as a single element to a `[]string`, which is invalid; your `Count` logic cannot work since the map is recreated every time through the loop; your `MyStruct` type is defined inside the loop (which technically works but is very odd).

Comment: Oh, the Words string was a typo. Sorry for that. How can I handle the MyStruct and Count Logic then

Answer (score 2):

Something like that, than marshal to json

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

var StringsArray = []string{"Person1", "Person2", "Person3",
                            "Person4", "Person1", "Person2"}

type MyStruct struct {
    Name string
    Count int
}

func main() {
    mySlice := []MyStruct{}

    for i, name := range StringsArray {
        fmt.Println(name, i)
        mySlice = append(
            mySlice,
            MyStruct{
                Name: name,
                Count: i,
            })
        
    }
    fmt.Println(mySlice)
}
```

you can try it here - [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_tntSKFLiOX)

Answer (score 0):

The code mentioned above will have compilation issues. However based on the input-output mentioned, the following modification of your code should give you the desired results

```
package main

import "fmt"

var StringsArray = []string{"Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4", "Person1", "Person2"}

type MyStruct struct {
    Name  string 
    Count int    
}

func main() {
    countArray := []MyStruct{}
    Count := make(map[string]int)
    for _, name := range StringsArray {
        Count[name] += 1
    }

    for name, cnt := range Count {
        countArray = append(countArray, MyStruct{Name: name, Count: cnt})
    }

    fmt.Println(countArray)
}
```

Playground Link - https://play.golang.org/p/tg4s30w98db